# HttpURLConnection getResponseCode() deos not return if there is no Internet connection

Tags: android, web-services, httpurlconnection, android-webservice, ws-client

I am using a `HttpURLConnection` to check whether the server URL is available or not by using the following code:

```
try {
    boolean connectionFailed = false;
    URL knownURL = new URL("http://www.google.com");
    httpConnection = (HttpURLConnection) knownURL.openConnection();
    httpConnection.setConnectTimeout(5000);
    responseCode = httpConnection.getResponseCode();
    if (responseCode != 200)  {
        status = ConnectionStatus.NOT_CONNECTED; 
    }
}
catch(Exception e) {
    connctionFailed = true;
}
```

This code is working fine under normal conditions. But when there is no Internet connection (because either the router is disconnected or not the hotspot), `httpConnection.getResponseCode()` is not executed (the function does not return). How can I fix this?

Comment: Try to put code snippet in `TRY CATCH Block`. What i suspect is `(HttpURLConnection) knownURL.openConnection();` throws a socket exception when there is no internet, so you're not reaching to ` httpConnection.getResponseCode();`

Comment: knownURL.openConnection() is executing and it's not coming to catch block. It's stop on when calling getResponseCode()

Comment: try debugging it. And yes, you are getting an exception. That's why. Check your logcat and post here maybe.

Comment: HttpUrlConnection works without internet?

Answer (score 6):

`httpConnection.setConnectTimeout(5000)` 
is a timeout for connection.

This is not a timeout for `httpConnection.getResponseCode()`.

If you add `httpConnection.setReadTimeout(2000)`, `httpConnection.getResponseCode()`should throw an exception when no connection is available.

Comment: This seems as it should be causing the getResponseCode() to start throwing TimeOutExceptions. Did it?

I have similar problem and am looking for the simple solution, without having to program the timeouts myself.

Comment: It could also be the DNS look that's failing, and that doesn't have a timeout the user can specify. It also throws a different type of exception which you might not catch, depending on how you're catching the exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

You may be having a try catch block at higher layer which is catching the sockettimeout exception.